# Microsoft Visual Studio CSS Validation Errors link to wrong file

Tags: css, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors

I have a strange situation.  I have a new web project in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.

I right clicked on it and went to Add Existing Items to add a couple of .css files from an existing project that are exactly what I need.  Hovering over these they now show saved in my new project folder.  When I compile the project I receive validation (css 2.1): errors for these files.  When clicking on the errors it does not open up the file in the project.  Instead it opens up the .css file from the path of the old project.  I can't figure out why.

I'd love to make these errors go away but

1. It would be nice if I could click on the errors to open up the file that really needs corrected.
2. Even after modifying the line in both the old and new and recompiling I still get the error.  For instance I am getting

Error   1   Validation (CSS 2.1): 'width:' is not a valid value for the 'page-break-inside' property.   C:\oldpath\oldfile.css  28  5

It is complaining about the oldfile, not the newly inserted one that is in c:\newpath.  You can see the width line it is complaining about below.  Looks completely legal to me.  It was originally missing the ; on the line before it.

```
.datatables
{
page-break-inside:auto;   
width: 600px; 
margin: 0; 
float: none;  
}
```

Any help pointing me where to look would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell the answer is to completely close your project (after saving of course) close out of Visual Studio 2010, reopen Visual Studio, reopen your project and recompile again and the errors you fixed magically go away and clicking on the remaining errors open the correct .css file.  If anyone knows why this happens or how to prevent this behavior I will mark your answer as the more accepted one.